# MongoDB: get documents by tags

Tags: mongodb, tags

I've got documents containing `tags` array. I want to provide tags based recommendations on site, so I need to get documents containing same tags + documents that don't match 1 tag + documents that don't match 2 tags and etc...

How do I do that?

Comment: Given what you said below this question is not clear.  Maybe an example of desired output would help

Answer (score 29, accepted):

example collection:

```
db.tags.insert({"tags":["red", "tall", "cheap"]});
db.tags.insert({"tags":["blue", "tall", "expensive"]});
db.tags.insert({"tags":["blue", "little", "cheap"]});
```

find all that include the tag "blue"

```
db.tags.find({tags: { $elemMatch: { $eq: "blue" } }})
```

find all tagged "blue" and only blue

```
db.tags.find({tags: "blue"})
```

find all tagged "blue" and "cheap"

```
db.tags.find({ tags: { $all: ["cheap", "blue"] } } )
```

find all not "blue"

```
db.tags.find({tags: { $ne: "blue" } })
```

find all "blue" and "cheap" but not "red" and not "tall"

not possible in my mongo db. From mongodb 1.9.1 on something like this should work, though (not tested):

```
db.tags.find({ $and: [ {tags: { $all: ["blue", "cheap"] } }, { tags: { $nin: ["red", "tall"] } } ] })
```

Comment: You didn't get the idea. I don't need exact match. I want all documents containing at least one of the tags ordered by count of original tags it includes.

Comment: would you care to formulate the question more precisely then?

Comment: use the `$in` operator to find  some but not `$all`, this answer mislead me to believe that `$all` behaved like `$in` https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in

Answer (score 1):

The rephrased question is:

Suppose if job postings have search tags attached like

Job Postings

```
[{_id : ObjectId(1249999493),tags : ['Location1', 'SkillSet1', 'SkillSet2', 'Someother1', 'Someother2']},
 {_id : ObjectId(1249999494),tags : ['Location3', 'SkillSet1', 'SkillSet0', 'Someother4', 'Someother3']}]
```

Now, he wants the records having tags ['Location1','SkillSet1', 'SkillSet0']

And the selected docs having more keywords from the query should come first. Less keywords matching should come last. So, that one can get more suitable job posting for the search query.

Am I sensible or do I need to re-phrase ?

Comment: That looks right to me. Seems that the ***4 year old question*** was talking more about filtering results than creating search parameters.

Comment: @nilsi yes this is not an answer but I tried to explain the problem with a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Find matching products which contains any of the specified keys.
2. Unfold on keys
3. Do find again to filter unwanted after unfolding
4. Group them by adding key occurrence
5. Sort desc to get most relevant first

[{ "$match" : { "keys" : { "$in" : [ { "$regex" : "text" , "$options" : "i"}]}}}, { "$unwind" : "$keys"}, { "$match" : { "keys" : { "$in" : [ { "$regex" : "text" , "$options" : "i"}]}}}, { "$group" : { "_id" : { "productId" : "$productId"} , "relatedTags" : { "$sum" : 1} }}, { "$sort" : { "relatedTags" : -1}},{ "$limit" : 10}]