# MongoDB Tags Key Indexing

Tags: mongodb, tags, indexing, multikey

Going over some of the tutorials I have found [MongoDB: get documents by tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940503/mongodb-get-documents-by-tags), it seems that most tags are created as list of items. In my schema I want dynamic tags (key-value pairs), so every item in the collection has a tags field like the following entry:

```
{"tags" : {"key1" : "value1", "key2", "value2"}}
```

However I'd like indexing on the keys inside the tags field. AFAIK, this is not possible (even with multikey indexes), since the keys can be arbitrary?

Will I need to migrate the schema to look like:

```
{"tags" : [{"key1" : "value1"}, {"key2" : "value2"}]}
```

If so would my index look like:

```
db.foo.ensureIndex({"tags" : 1})
```

As suggested here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+Multikeys+to+Simulate+a+Large+Number+of+Indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can index over an array of subdocuments as tags, but you always need to query for the complete sub-document. create the index as you stated above with

```
db.foo.ensureIndex({'tags': 1})
```

and query with:

```
db.foo.find('tags': {'key1': 'value1'})
```

This will use the index and return all documents that have that particular sub-document in their tags array.

Comment: crap, sorry I meant to say {"tags" : [{"key1" : "value1"}, {"key2" : "value2"}]} not {"tags" : [{"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2"}]}. I'm not sure if that changes anything however.